# How to filter the list of dictionaries if its key is in the filtered list?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using code to filter the output (which is a list of dictionaries) according to the predetermined list (in code: filteredList).

I tried the ***outcome variable*** to filter the list of dictionaries.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pprint

urls = ['https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=1',
        'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases?page=2'
        ]


def get_soup(url):
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    return soup


def pageNumber(url):
    response = requests.get('https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases')
    soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")
    content = str(soup.find("li", class_="disabled PagedList-pageCountAndLocation").find("a", recursive=False))
    number = int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, content))) / 100
    return int(number)


print(pageNumber('https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/Cases'))


filteredList = ['AZƏRBAYCAN DƏMİR YOLLARI',
                '"AZƏRSU" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ'
                ]
outcomes = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        soup = get_soup(url)
        detail_urls = [f'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/CaseDetail?caseId={i["value"]}' for i in
                       soup.select('.caseId')]
        for next_url in detail_urls:
            soup = get_soup(next_url)
            data = [string for string in soup.select_one('[colspan="4"]').stripped_strings]
            for i in data:
                for j in filteredList:
                        if i in j:
                            outcomes.append(data)
                        else:
                            pass

print(outcomes)

myFile = open('csvexample.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(outcomes)
```

Two problems here:
1. it returns empty lists which should not
**2. the output returns only fitered key of dictionaries in the list like below** (['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Vüqar Həsənov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Namiq Cəfərov - tərkib üzvü', 'Şərafət Məmmədova - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', '"AZƏRSU" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'İddiaçı:', 'DƏMİROV ELMƏDDİN ƏNVƏR OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Sair mülki iş - Kommunal xərcləri ilə bağlı istehlakçıların hüquqlarının müdafiəsi'] ***instead of the only filtered part which is ['"AZƏRSU" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ']***)

```py
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Tofiq Səmədov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Elşən Kazımov - tərkib üzvü', 'İkram Şirinov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', '"Travelers Coffee Limited" Şirkətinin Azərbaycan Respublikasındakı Filialı', 'İddiaçı:', 'Məmmədov Vaqif İsmayıl', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'İcarə müqaviləsi üzrə mübahisələr - Digər icarə müqavilələri']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'İlham Kərimli - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Xəyalə Cəmilova - tərkib üzvü', 'İsmayıl Xəlilov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'MİLYAYEVA NATALYA VASİLYEVNA', 'İddiaçı:', 'ƏLİYEV AKİF MUXTAR OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Mülkiyyət hüququ ilə əlaqədar mübahisələr - Digər']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Şeyda Məhərrəmova - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Elşad Şamayev - tərkib üzvü', 'Məmməd Məmmədov - tərkib üzvü', 'Xəyal Sarıyev - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'ZÖHRABOV ORXAN RAMİZ OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'RZAYEV ƏLİBALA VASİF OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'ƏSGƏROV RUHİN İBRAHİM OĞLU', 'İddiaçı:', 'ALLAHVERDİYEVA MƏLAHƏT GÖYÜŞ QIZI', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Mənzil mübahisələri - Mənzildən çıxarılma', 'Müqavilənin etibarsız hesab edilməsi tələbi üzrə']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Xəyal Sarıyev - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Elşad Şamayev - tərkib üzvü', 'Məmməd Məmmədov - tərkib üzvü', 'Şeyda Məhərrəmova - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'BAXIŞOV AZAD SİRAC OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'KAZIMOV İLHAM DAVUD OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', '"MƏKAN" MƏNZİL-TİKİNTİ KOOPERATİVİ', 'Cavabdeh:', 'İSAYEVA QƏTİBƏ İSMAYIL QIZI', 'Cavabdeh:', 'BAXIŞOV AZƏR SİRAC OĞLU', 'İddiaçı:', 'HÜSEYNOV CAHANGİR HÜSEYN', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Sair mülki iş - Digər']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'İsmayıl Xəlilov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Xəyalə Cəmilova - tərkib üzvü', 'İlham Kərimli - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'Rzayev Fəxrəddin Hidayət', 'Cavabdeh:', 'Rzayev Fəxrəddin', 'Cavabdeh:', 'RZAYEVA İRADƏ ELXAN QIZI', 'İddiaçı:', 'Dəmirov Davud Nüsrət', 'İddiaçı:', 'DƏMİROV DAVUD NÜSRƏT', 'İddiaçı:', 'Rzayeva İradə E', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Mülki hüquq pozuntularından (deliktlərdən) əmələ gələn öhdəliklər üzrə mübahisələr - Maddi ziyanın ödənilməsi']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Xumar Mərdanova - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Elnur Həsənov - tərkib üzvü', 'Fuad Babayev - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'MƏMMƏDOV SƏFƏR MƏHƏRLƏM OĞLU', 'İddiaçı:', 'ALLAHVERDİYEV BAYRAM MƏHƏRRƏM', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Sair mülki iş - Digər']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Fuad Babayev - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Elnur Həsənov - tərkib üzvü', 'Xumar Mərdanova - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', '"DAŞINAR VƏ DAŞINMAZ ƏMLAKLARIN QİYMƏTLƏNDİRİLMƏSİ XİDMƏTİ" MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'Cavabdeh:', '"DAŞINAR  VƏ DAŞINMAZ ƏMLAKLARIN SATIŞI ÜZRƏ HƏRRAC MƏRKƏZİ"  MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'İddiaçı:', 'MURADOV İSMAYIL KAMRAN OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'İpoteka müqaviləsi üzrə mübahisələr - İpoteka müqaviləsi ilə bağlı digər mübahisələr']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Abiddin Hüseynov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Azad İmanov - tərkib üzvü', 'Vahid Sadıqov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'HƏRRAC MƏRKƏZİ "KÜLƏK" MMC', 'İddiaçı:', 'MUSAYEVA TƏRANƏ MURQUZ QIZI', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'İpoteka müqaviləsi üzrə mübahisələr - İpoteka üzrə hərracın nəticələrinin ləğv edilməsi üzrə mübahisələr']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Vüqar Həsənov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Namiq Cəfərov - tərkib üzvü', 'Şərafət Məmmədova - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', **'"AZƏRSU" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ'**, 'İddiaçı:', 'DƏMİROV ELMƏDDİN ƏNVƏR OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Sair mülki iş - Kommunal xərcləri ilə bağlı istehlakçıların hüquqlarının müdafiəsi']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Şərafət Məmmədova - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Namiq Cəfərov - tərkib üzvü', 'Vüqar Həsənov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'AĞAYEV FƏRİD RASİM OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'ABBASOV RASİM AĞA OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'ABBASOVA ƏNTİQƏ ŞAHSUVAR QIZI', 'Cavabdeh:', 'ABBASOV AĞA HƏMİŞ OĞLU', 'İddiaçı:', 'MUSAYEV ELŞƏN İSA OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Mənzil mübahisələri - Mənzilə istifadə hüququna xitam verilməsi']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Vüqar Həsənov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', '"BAKU ELECTRONİCS" MƏHDUD MƏSULİYYƏTLİ CƏMİYYƏTİ', 'İddiaçı:', 'CƏFƏROV AĞA HƏSƏN OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Torpaq mübahisələri - Torpaq münasibətləri üzrə sair mübahisələr']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Abiddin Hüseynov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Azad İmanov - tərkib üzvü', 'Vahid Sadıqov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'HÜSEYNOVA AYNUR VAQİF', 'İddiaçı:', 'ƏLİZADƏ TÜRKEL SƏRVƏR QIZI', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Əmək mübahisələri - Əmək haqqı tələbi']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Aida Hüseyn - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Etibar Nəbiyev - tərkib üzvü', 'Raqib Qurbanov - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'AZƏRBAYCAN TİBB UNİVERSİTETİNİN TƏDRİS CƏRRAHİYYƏ KLİNİKASI', 'Cavabdeh:', 'NƏSİRLİ CƏFƏR ƏLİABBAS OĞLU', 'Cavabdeh:', 'QƏNBƏROV HƏSƏNAĞA MƏMİ', 'Cavabdeh:', 'MƏRKƏZİ DƏNİZCİLƏR XƏSTƏXANASI', 'Cavabdeh:', 'MƏMMƏDOVA HƏCƏR TOFİQ', 'Cavabdeh:', 'BİO LAP TİBB MARKƏZ', 'İddiaçı:', 'ƏLƏKBƏROV XƏYYAM ÜZEYİR OĞLU', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Mülki hüquq pozuntularından (deliktlərdən) əmələ gələn öhdəliklər üzrə mübahisələr - Maddi ziyanın ödənilməsi', 'Mülki hüquq pozuntularından (deliktlərdən) əmələ gələn öhdəliklər üzrə mübahisələr - Mənəvi zərərin ödənilməsi']
['Ətraflı məlumat:', 'İşə baxan hakim və ya tərkib', 'Raqib Qurbanov - sədrlik edən hakim', 'Aida Hüseyn - tərkib üzvü', 'Etibar Nəbiyev - tərkib üzvü', 'Tərəflər', 'Cavabdeh:', 'SALMANOV VÜSAL SALMAN OĞLU', 'İddiaçı:', '"TEXNİKABANK" AÇIQ SƏHMDAR CƏMİYYƏTİ (Ləğv prosesindədir)', 'İşin mahiyyəti', 'Kredit müqaviləsi üzrə mübahisələr']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last code to:

```
import csv

outcomes = []
    with requests.Session() as s:
        for url in urls:
            soup = get_soup(url)
            detail_urls = [f'https://e-mehkeme.gov.az/Public/CaseDetail?caseId={i["value"]}' for i in
                           soup.select('.caseId')]
            for next_url in detail_urls:
                soup = get_soup(next_url)
                data = [string for string in soup.select_one('[colspan="4"]').stripped_strings]
                for i in data:
                    for j in filteredList:
                            if i in j:
                                outcomes.append(data)
                            else:
                                pass

    print(outcomes)

    with open('csvexample.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
         writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
         writer.writerow(outcomes)
```

I would recommend to attach your outcomes to a list and return the list in the end instead of printing.

Comment: thanks but it does not solve the second problem, output include only filtered part of dictionary but dictionary have other key and values, i have updated the required output

Comment: I had to see what your output is. I adapted your code. I like it more like this as it is easier to read.

Comment: sorry i should include it, is it understandable now?

Comment: I edited the code. It should work now. But you should check, as I don't speak your language. It returns every key, if it contains a word of your filtered keys.

Comment: it does not return the output i want, i am editing the question that how it should looks like

Comment: you can see the result before filter and i want to get the whole dictionary that have the string between the list of dictionaries

Comment: Ah ok I think I got it now. You simply change, what do you want to append. So you loop over the data list, check if i is in one of the filteredlist strings and if yes, you append the whole list, which is the data. See the edited code.

Comment: great, it works now thanks a lot, i am now converting it to csv could please look that code it is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200553/discussion-between-vali-valizada-and-pyseeker).

Comment: This edit works now for me. Good luck with the rest.

Comment: mylist? there is no variable like that did you mean outputs? an i tried with writerow(outputs) it fails

Comment: Check my last edit. Yeah it is outcomes instead of mylist. You need to define the encoder.

Comment: how to change the encoding? it is not suitible for my language.

Comment: utf-8 does not work? Mhm check encoding styles and the unicode encoder of your python system. In my machine utf-8 wotrks with your dataset.

Comment: It retruns like that
['ЖЏtraflД± mЙ™lumat:', 'Д°ЕџЙ™ baxan hakim vЙ™ ya tЙ™rkib', 'VГјqar HЙ™sЙ™nov - sЙ™drlik edЙ™n hakim', 'Namiq CЙ™fЙ™rov - tЙ™rkib ГјzvГј', 'ЕћЙ™rafЙ™t MЙ™mmЙ™dova - tЙ™rkib ГјzvГј', 'TЙ™rЙ™flЙ™r', 'Cavabdeh:', '"AZЖЏRSU" AГ‡IQ SЖЏHMDAR CЖЏMД°YYЖЏTД°', 'Д°ddiaГ§Д±:', 'DЖЏMД°ROV ELMЖЏDDД°N ЖЏNVЖЏR OДћLU', 'Д°Еџin mahiyyЙ™ti', 'Sair mГјlki iЕџ - Kommunal xЙ™rclЙ™ri ilЙ™ baДџlД± istehlakГ§Д±larД±n hГјquqlarД±nД±n mГјdafiЙ™si']

Comment: thanks it is working with my macbook, but in my work pc it return as above. what do you think the problem is?

Comment: As I said it is an encoding problem. You should check the unicode encoder used for python and your working machine. Standard python unicode encoder is utf-8. Maybe your work machine has a different as you are using a cyrillic alphabet?

Comment: I will check it, thanks, and is there any way to speed up the running time? it takes to long to retrieve the data? am I supposed to right a cleaner?

Comment: could you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58218685/using-http-request-get-output-of-each-manually-search-automatically